# DocumentDB returning different result count every time on large paged fetch

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

## The Problem

I'm trying to pull roughly 20,000 documents out of docdb. To reduce the amount I'm fetching, I'm only pulling out the document's ID. I'm paging through the results and when I've built up a list after it's done, I've found that the number of results changes (and they're all wrong!). It's not getting all of the results it should. There are no other processes that are currently touching the data.

Here's an idea of how I'm querying:

```
var sql = new SqlQuerySpec(@"SELECT items.id FROM items WHERE items.foo = @bar")
{
    Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection { new SqlParameter("@bar", bar) }
};

var feedOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 2000 };
var query = this.Context.Client.CreateDocumentQuery<Foo>(dbSelfLink, sql, feedOptions).AsDocumentQuery();

var ids = new List<string>();

while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
    var page = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Foo>().ConfigureAwait(false);
    ids.AddRange(page.AsEnumerable());
}
```

I ran this three times while debugging and got three different ID counts:

```
19,323
19,321
19,327
```

And none of these are quite as high as I expect them. They're within 100 or so of what I expect.

## What I've Ruled Out

- It isn't a deserialization problem because I've tried changing the
  query to select an ID that wasn't in the result set and it grabs it
  fine.
- It isn't the query itself, as I can run the same query in the Azure
  portal's query explorer with an additional `AND items.id = '...'`
  looking for a specific missing ID and it returns it.
- It isn't the way I'm doing paging, because I've used this same method
  elsewhere for smaller queries (~100 results) and it works fine.
- It isn't because I'm crossing the data center boundary, as this
  happens in production as well.

## What I Suspect

It could be that I'm being rate limited (my two collections are S2), but I'm not sure why that would change the number of results, or how I would prove that. I may try to upgrade the collections to S3 to see if that fixes the problem, but that wouldn't work for me long-term.

Other than that, I'd really appreciate any insight into what might be happening. Thanks!

### Edit

I tried upgrading the collections. No change.

### Edit 2 with response to comments

Yes, we are using lazy indexing...I was beginning to wonder if that was the culprit but not sure why that would result in not getting all of our records. If this needs to change, that's probably okay, as the indexing was originally done without much thought (and it's using an old format which you can see here). Below is the indexing policy:

```
{
  "indexingMode": "Lazy",
  "automatic": true,
  "includedPaths": [
    {
      "path": "/",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "kind": "Hash",
          "dataType": "Number",
          "precision": 3
        },
        {
          "kind": "Hash",
          "dataType": "String",
          "precision": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "/\"_ts\"/?",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "kind": "Range",
          "dataType": "Number",
          "precision": 6
        },
        {
          "kind": "Hash",
          "dataType": "String",
          "precision": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "excludedPaths": []
}
```

Regarding the `MaxItemCount`, I have also tried with -1 and saw similar behavior.

Comment: Can you please include your indexing policy - are you using Lazy indexing by chance? Also the reason you're seeing a different number of results per-page might be due to rate limiting, but you should see the same total number of results.

Comment: It will also help narrow down the problem if you could post the results of execution with "SELECT VALUE items.id FROM items WHERE items.foo = @bar" and MaxItemCount = -1 (-1 denotes maximum possible page size).

Comment: Edited above with the info you requested. To clarify, I'm fine with seeing a different number of results per page, but yeah, I'm actually seeing a different total number. Very odd. And yes, tried with MaxItemCount = -1 as well as a few others to see if that helped, but there was no change in behavior. Thanks a ton for helping me work through this!

Comment: Can you please modify the collection to Consistent indexing, wait for it to complete (100%), then retry this? 
Lazy indexing as the name suggests is performed as a low priority process. Since DocumentDB maintains multiple replicas of every collection, you might have replicas that are further ahead or behind in terms of which documents are indexed. And because requests are routed randomly for load-balancing, you can see results that are "eventually consistent" based on the replica that's selected (with lazy indexing). Eventually, they will all catch up and return the same results.

Comment: I'll give this a shot, but while I'm at it I will also change what fields are indexed since I don't want all of the document's properties to be indexed (I inherited our current indexing policy...it wasn't something I set up). Let me know if that's a problem. I may not get back to you on this until Monday, just FYI. Until then, thanks a ton for the help so far!

Comment: This fixed the problem. I got the same number of results twice in a row and that number is now 19,793...way more than I ever got before. Thanks again for your help. If you'd like to post an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99429/discussion-between-aravind-ramachandran-and-planetlotus).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're using the Lazy indexing mode. Lazy indexing as the name suggests is performed as a low priority process relative to writes and serves "eventually consistent results" to queries.

Since DocumentDB maintains multiple replicas of every collection (for HA and performance), you might have replicas that are further ahead or behind in terms of which documents are indexed.

Because each page request within a query is routed randomly by the client/gateway for load-balancing, you can see results that can contain/miss results based on which replicas are selected. Eventually, when indexing is up to date on all replicas, queries will return the same number of results.

If you would like consistent query results, you can switch the collection to use Consistent indexing mode.